# How can PCA be used with a lot of empty values in Python for medical data?

Tags: python, pca

I'm working on a project to detect diseases in humans. I have an Excel file that has the data of different metabolites causing certain diseases (we'll call them disease 1 (D1) and disease 2 (D2)). The data contains three control columns (control-1, control-2, and control-3), along with Disease state columns, telling us whether the person is suffering from D1 or D2. The remaining columns are of the metabolites (named according to the name of the metabolite and the time at which the metabolite is detected when the device is put on the patient). The values in these metabolite columns describe the area under the curve when the device is being used on the person (the patch is applied for up to 35 minutes). In total there are 200 rows, and 5300 columns.

My question is, since there are a lot of empty datapoints (since different metabolites are detected in different people at different times), how do I use PCA here?

I tried seperating the disease state and the remaining dataset into features and targets, however I'm quite new to PCA so don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Why don't you use PCA like you would otherwise?

Comment: It would help to see your code. Not all PCA libraries behave the same.

Comment: Using PCA with a lot of NaN can be tricky, you can use the ALS approach to solve this, since EVD or SVD will not work well. Btw ALS is alternating least square, EVD is eigenvalue decomp and SVD is singular value decomp. IF you turn your question into a reproducible example, we might be able to help you further

Comment: Also, if you are interested in the theory behind such a question, better ask this at crossvalidated

Answer (score 1):

### Dealing with missing values

It really depends on the context.

That is the very broad problem of missing data in AI in general.

Usually there are 3 methods to consider

1. Remove the samples where there are some missing data
2. Remove the variables with too many missing data
3. Find a way to interpolate and fill missing values

The 3rd method is usally a bad idea when trying to learn. That implies that you already have a model to be able to fill missing variableᵢ for all other variableⱼ j≠i.
And if you had, you wouldn't be trying to learn a model...

Plus, if there are more than a few missing values (in which case, method 1 is a better way to interpolate: it is the model learnt from the rest that will interpolate) filling with a predefined rule is risking that your learned model will just learn that rule.

Method 2 is a big sacrifice usually. It is what people usually have already done before even trying to model things: the measure campaign of variableK wasn't efficient, and we cannot count of variableK. Let's do our study without taking variableK into account.

So, the easier and cheaper (in terms of sacrifice and hypothesis) is method 1. Just drop the incomplete samples (in your case, the patients for which you don't have all data are removed from the study).
That is quite an obvious method if you think about it. You have 1000 patients. But 400 of them have some missing values. Let compute the model with the  600 that have all values.
600 is still significative enough.

### Specific case of PCA

All that being said, for PCA, situation is more lenient.
Because you don't really need to have a significant number of samples with all variables. You just need it *for any pair of variables*.

Which is not the same.

Because PCA works only from the covariance matrix anyway. Which is the K² coefficients of covariance for all pair of the K variables.
So, it doesn't matter if none of your patients have all the variables. As long as for any pair of variable you consider, their are a significant amount of patients that have both.

### Example code

Just to play a bit with those situation, see following codes.

To start with, a data generator to simulate the situation.
I've arbitrarily chosen to make 1000 samples of 20 variables, but those 20 variables (but for a small noise) are all linear combination of 2 hidden variables X and Y. Said otherwise, in reality sample space is not a 20-dimension space, but a 2-dimension space: in the 20-dimension space, all my samples are distributed (but a small noise) on a place.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# Generate nsample lines of nvar columns
# But for a noise, columns are linear combination of only 2 hidden variables X, Y
# X+Y, X+2Y, X+3Y, X+4Y, ...
# So, PCA shoud see 2 big axis, being thos X and Y
def generateData(nsample, nvar):
    X=3*np.random.uniform(-1,1,(nsample,1))
    Y=np.random.uniform(-1,1,(nsample,1))
    data = X + Y*np.arange(1,nvar+1) + np.random.normal(0,0.3,(nsample, nvar))
    return data

# Place nnan randomly positionned in data
# (well, at most nnan: 2 of the random coordinates could be identical
def randomNan(data, nnan):
    data[np.random.randint(0,data.shape[0], (nnan,)), np.random.randint(0, data.shape[1], (nnan,))] = np.nan
data=generateData(1000,20)
```

### Perfect case, no missing value, sklearn PCA

With full data, we can use sklearn to compute a PCA

```
pca=PCA()
pca.fit(data)
print("With PCA")
print("Explained variance ", pca.explained_variance_)
# Note: I can compute that only because I cheat: I know that in reality my columns are X+Y, X+2Y, ...
# Which is useful to test pertinence of PCA
# A normal user, with real data, of course, can only see from explained variance that most of the information lies in 2 1st axis
print("First axis in term of X, Y coefficient", pca.components_[0].sum(),(pca.components_[0]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
print("2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient", pca.components_[1].sum(),(pca.components_[1]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
```

It displays in my case

```
With PCA
Explained variance  [9.71524496e+02 1.30566437e+01 1.09812988e-01 1.05226866e-01
 1.04608272e-01 1.00939601e-01 9.81508274e-02 9.57280159e-02
 9.41453137e-02 9.11923313e-02 9.01281715e-02 8.82283578e-02
 8.52329568e-02 8.25107518e-02 8.17336107e-02 7.85909592e-02
 7.57531734e-02 7.45379627e-02 6.92182448e-02 6.53931646e-02]
First axis in term of X, Y coefficient 3.9611591815820617 53.56216155462627
2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient -2.0757797619317437 1.0447242544331221
```

Which is consistent. As you can see, only the 2 first axis contain really some information. As expected, since those 20 variables were indeed generated from only 2 axis.

I can even tell that those axis are 4X+54Y and -2.1X+Y
(it doesn't matter a lot. But I'll use that to check later that our axis won't change a lot with other methods/situations)

### No missing value, "manual" computation

To be able to handle massive number of missing data, it is necessary (at least for me. I doubt I've invented anything new here. So, I am pretty sure that some PCA library can do all that themselves. But not sklearn) to go back to the definition of PCA: eigen values and vectors of the covariance matrix. Let's compute that on that perfect case (no missing value), just to check that it is indeed the same thing

```
# Redo the same thing by hand
print("Explicit cov/diag")
M=data.T@data/len(data)
val,vec=np.linalg.eig(M)
print("Eigen values", val)
print("First axis in term of X, Y coefficient", vec[:,0].sum(),(vec[:,0]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
print("2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient", vec[:,1].sum(),(vec[:,1]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
```

Result

```
Explicit cov/diag
Eigen values [9.70593530e+02 1.30587033e+01 6.53349522e-02 1.09708075e-01
 1.04521244e-01 1.05294550e-01 6.91895251e-02 1.00876037e-01
 9.80601811e-02 7.45198435e-02 7.57369369e-02 9.56482356e-02
 9.40764520e-02 7.85257295e-02 9.11048572e-02 9.00451242e-02
 8.82091765e-02 8.25103111e-02 8.16597671e-02 8.52298653e-02]
First axis in term of X, Y coefficient 3.9612128937810476 53.56213449612184
2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient -2.0756789336378865 1.046110457452679
```

As you can see, same result. All information lies in the 2 main axis. With the same 971, 13.1, ε, ε, ε, ... distribution.

And axis are the same (4X+54Y, -2.1X+Y).

### With 100 Nans

Now, remove some values.

```
randomNan(data,100)
```

We can still work with sklearn. We have 100 missing values in 1000 lines. No big deal. In worst case, we can still work with 900 lines.
Let's just remove the lines with at least one missing variable

```
rest=data[~(np.isnan(data).any(axis=1))]
```

And do the exact same thing on the remaining lines

```
pca=PCA()
pca.fit(rest)
print("Explained variance ", pca.explained_variance_)
print("First axis in term of X, Y coefficient", pca.components_[0].sum(),(pca.components_[0]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
print("2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient", pca.components_[1].sum(),(pca.components_[1]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
```

Result remain similar

```
Explained variance  [9.60927526e+02 1.30843743e+01 1.11122015e-01 1.06633816e-01
 1.04743738e-01 1.02313515e-01 9.89355641e-02 9.55257969e-02
 9.28624769e-02 9.13829790e-02 8.78148280e-02 8.57535378e-02
 8.47455412e-02 8.30031936e-02 7.94103530e-02 7.78999202e-02
 7.51900162e-02 7.24853152e-02 6.85913907e-02 6.52283678e-02]
First axis in term of X, Y coefficient 3.9624936028367514 53.56147739402379
2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient -2.073217794793028 1.0791109578209714
```

Likewise with "manual" method

```
M=rest.T@rest/len(rest)
val,vec=np.linalg.eig(M)
print("Eigen values", val)
print("First axis in term of X, Y coefficient", vec[:,0].sum(),(vec[:,0]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
print("2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient", vec[:,1].sum(),(vec[:,1]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
```

Result

```
Eigen values [9.60495955e+02 1.30789581e+01 1.11004855e-01 6.51829089e-02
 1.06755956e-01 1.04629487e-01 6.85162017e-02 1.02200809e-01
 9.88342449e-02 7.24928013e-02 9.54206124e-02 7.51126865e-02
 9.27744132e-02 9.12841914e-02 7.78364588e-02 7.93604232e-02
 8.77273031e-02 8.29302040e-02 8.57346451e-02 8.47068638e-02]
First axis in term of X, Y coefficient 3.9626589253876006 53.56139127704072
2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient -2.07290279368996 1.083379415469587
```

### The interesting part : lot of missing values

Let's remove 10000 values

```
randomNan(data,10000)
print(len(data[~(np.isnan(data).any(axis=1))]),"row(s) left")
```

Chance are that there won't be any complete row, or very few of them after than. In my case

```
0 row(s) left
```

So, impossible to work with sklearn directly here. (I've haven't shown what happens if you try to `PCA.fit(data)` without removing missing sows. But you get an error. An explicit one telling "there can't be missing values")

But the "manual" method just need a covariance matrix.
That is, a matrix, that gives for all pair i,j of columns Mᵢⱼ = (Σ xₖᵢxₖⱼ)/n

where xₖᵢ is the ith variable of the kth sample. And n is the number of sample.

If you have some missing values for variable i and j, just count with the rest. As long as you have a significant number n of samples with both i and j, the covariance with be accurate enough. And it doesn't matter if for another pair i',j' of variables it is some other samples that provide the estimation of the covariance. As long as there are enough of those too. We don't need sample with i, j, i', j' available. Just enough with i,j available. And enough with i',j' available. Not necessarily the sames.

So, let's do that, let's compute for all i,j (Σxₖᵢxₖⱼ)/n. Which we can do in a fast vectorized way like this:

```
# data0 is data, but with 0 instead of nan (so that xₖᵢxₖⱼ is 0 when i or j is missing for sample k, and that sample doesn't contribute in Σ sum)
data0 = np.where(~np.isnan(data), data, 0)
# And compute "n" for each pair i,j (if we counted the term xₖᵢₖⱼ as 0, the we must not count it in "n", to have a correct average of xₖᵢxₖⱼ)
# That can be done with some broadcasting yoga
# np.isnan(data[:,:,None]) | np.isnan(data[:,None,:]) is a 3d array giving
# for each (k,i,j), that is sample k, variables i and j
# True iff either i or j is Nan in sample k
# So with a ~ prefix, it is the reverse. And the sum along axis k tells 
# for how many sample neither i nor j is Nan
M=data0.T@data0 / (~(np.isnan(data[:,:,None]) | np.isnan(data[:,None,:]))).sum(axis=0)
# So M is, like in classical method, an estimation from the data of the covariance
# it is accurate enough is the previous denominator is big enough everywhere
# that is if, for any pair i,j of variables, there are enough samples containing both
val,vec=np.linalg.eig(M)
print("Eigen values", val)
print("First axis in term of X, Y coefficient", vec[:,0].sum(),(vec[:,0]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
print("2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient", vec[:,1].sum(),(vec[:,1]*np.arange(1,1+data.shape[1])).sum())
```

Result

```
Eigen values [ 9.66599218e+02  1.25428322e+01  8.86089683e+00 -7.99555924e+00
  7.61513471e+00  6.54319510e+00  4.00908285e+00 -5.83463195e+00
 -4.93809042e+00  2.69571556e+00  2.07317028e+00 -3.34829410e+00
 -2.61606289e+00 -2.30745328e+00  9.23032916e-01  5.91919085e-01
  3.89519307e-02 -1.59610747e-01 -4.52639684e-01 -1.19346575e+00]
First axis in term of X, Y coefficient -3.9652288197914287 -53.54301691284088
2nd axis in term of X, Y coefficient -1.9420128491159303 1.0300488213226298
```

As you can see, still good.
Even with 10100 missing values, and, more importantly, not a single complete sample (in my case 40% of the values or missing), you still get the same 2 main axis.

With most AI techniques, you would be doomed with that many missing value (unless you fill it with a special value meaning "missing" and hope for the AI to magically find a way to handle it. But that need some quite deep learning, and therefore require still a huge amount of data). Because most AI techniques (and that is also their strength) compute model that use all variables as a whole, not just separately each pairs of variables. PCA assumes that life is linear.

So, that is why, even when none of the 3 techniques mentioned at the beginning (and in the first pages of any data-science course), you can still work with PCA. If you remember what it is in reality: just a diagonalisation of a covariance matrix. As long as you can reasonnably compute the covariance matrix, you are off the hook.